# C++ Exiting a loop from a certain key hit

Tags: c++

So I have this function in my class that reads in these three variables until numSale equals 10, or else until "X" is entered. Currently, I can run this, but it does not exit. Any advice on how to make the loop quit if X is hit?

```
void Read()
   {
      string id;
      float  price;
      float  amount;

      cout << "Please enter your product id, unit price and amount of unit "
           << endl << "[id price amount] and enter X to finish:" << endl;
      // DO_5: use a while loop to read in sales objects to saleRecord array
     cin >> id >> price >> amount;
      while(id != "X" || numSale < MAX_RECORDS)
     {
        Sale sales(id, price, amount);
        saleRecord[numSale] = sales;
        ++numSale;
        cin >> id >> price >> amount;
     }
```

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
while(id != "X" || numSale < MAX_RECORDS)
```

into this:

```
while(id != "X" && numSale < MAX_RECORDS)
```

A `while` loop keeps running **as long as** the expression inside it is true.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to start off with checking that you stream is in good state. You want to check our input *after* reading it anyway:

```
while (numSale < MAX_RECORDS && std::cin >> id >> price >> amount && id != "X") {
    // do something with the input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you testing the exit? Could it be the case that `cin >> id >> price >> amount` is blocking waiting for a `price` and an `amount`?

In other words, if the user just enters

```
X <Enter>
```

Your program will still stay on the cin line until it finds two more inputs that it can parse as floats.